# How to protect or authenticate React route using react-router-dom amplify

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, aws-amplify

I'm building an application using React and amplify. The authentication and authorizations stuff a working properly. But it need to restrict the user from moving to some particular React routes before login in to the application. The following code snippet is what i have tried and it works if `isAuthenticated()` returns false. But since im using Amplify im  using a method

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={async props =>
      await isAuthenticated() ? (
        <Navigation>
          <Component {...props} />
        </Navigation>
      ) : (
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

here is my code for the isAuthenticated() function.

```
import Auth from "@aws-amplify/auth";
export const isAuthenticated = async () => {
  try {
    return await Auth.currentSession().isValid();
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

but this throws an error like this.

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I know this is because it returns a promise but im awaiting for it but it is not working as i thought any reason why? .

Answer (score 2):

change you private route component to the following:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)
  useEffect(async () => {
    const isAuth = await isAuthenticated()
    setIsLoggedIn(isAuth)
  }, [])
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        isLoggedIn ? (
          <Navigation>
            <Component {...props} />
          </Navigation>
        ) : (
            <Redirect to="/login" />
          )
      }
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the current state of React (as of today). It complains that useEffect can't take an async function, and recommends that you make an async function within the function that you pass to useEffect, and then call it immediately. On top of that, if you have a setup where going to the /login route while already authenticated forwards you to a /home page that forwards you to /login if you're unauthenticated, then you will get in a redirect loop. I wish there was a way to use the PrivateRoute pattern with AWS auth but it looks to me like there's not.

Answer (score 2):

I think better way to handle this is using redux saga, and definig array of protected routes.

**Router:**

```
function Router() {
    return (
        <Switch>
            <ProtectedRoute exact path="/">
                <Home/>
            </ProtectedRoute>
            <Route path="/login/">
                <Login/>
            </Route>
        </Switch>
    );
}

export default Router;
```

**PrivateRoute:**

```
Auth.configure(awsconfig);

function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {

    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

    const isAuthenticated = () => {

        setAuth(false);

        Auth.currentSession().then( response => {
            if(response.isValid()) {
                setAuth(true);
            } else {
                redirectToLogin();
            }
        }).catch(() => {
            redirectToLogin();
        });
    }

    const redirectToLogin = () => {
        history.push('/login');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        isAuthenticated();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Route {...rest}>
            { auth ? children : null }
        </Route>
    )
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

Comment: Thanks. Small addition: `const history = useHistory();` in the beginning of the function.